# Convert cv_bridge Image to cv::Mat image

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to have a pure OpenCV version `cv::Mat` of the Image on which I can do further modifications. I tried        `cv_ptr->dImg;` but it outputs errors. So far I have

```
 void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
   {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }
    
    // Draw an example circle on the video stream
    //if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
     // cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(px, py), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
        cv::Mat dImg;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225782/convert-cv_bridge-image-to-cv::mat-image/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess I figured it out. Did I make any mistakes?

```
cv::Mat dImg =  cv_ptr->image;
     double min = 0;
     double max = 1000;
cv::Mat img_scaled_8u;
cv::Mat(cv_ptr->image-min).convertTo(img_scaled_8u, CV_8UC1, 255. / (max - min));
cv::cvtColor(img_scaled_8u, dImg, CV_GRAY2RGB);
//if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
//cv::circle(dImg, cv::Point(px, py), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
// Update GUI Window
cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, dImg);
cv::waitKey(3);
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gushu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33421/gushu/) on 2018-05-24**:
I only needed the part of converting cv_bridge image to Mat. It worked for me - thanks!